# Mavericks tags are deleted when saving files

Tags: tags, osx-mavericks, acrobat

I'm trying to save a file after performing OCR using Acrobat Pro and for the tags I've assigned to files are deleted when saving. It looks like it's overwriting and not saving the file as is. Not sure what the difference is but I do know that "Spotlight Comments" are still there.

How can I save a file and not lost the tags?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an HFS+ filesystem - some filesystems, like FAT, probably don't support tags. Use the Info button in Disk Utility or Cmd+I in the Finder to check.

Comment: This is on Mavericks 10.9. The tags are supported and function properly except for when saving the file. When it's written from Acrobat it seems to delete the tags.

Comment: Would help to see some code.